# How to make exponential reference notations instead of bracketted references in the text

Tags: citing

How to change to exponential indication of references in the text using `\documentstyle{article}`. Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you really use `\documentstyle` instead of `\documentclass`? Put differently, are you adhering to LaTeX2.09 rather to LaTeX2e conventions? (LaTeX2e superseded LaTeX2.09 somewhere around 1994.) Many modern citation-related packages may not work correctly if run in so-called compatibility mode (which emulates LaTeX2.09 in a LaTeX2e container).

Comment: You mean superscript references?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean citation call-outs being formed as superscript-level numbers.

One way to get such citation call-outs is to load the `natbib` package with the option `super`. With this option loaded, `\cite{...}` commands will generate superscript numbers for citation call-outs. (Of course, you will also need to select a bibliography style to determine how entries are formatted in the bibliography section.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{zzz.bib}
@article{uvw,
  author = "Anne Author",
  title  = "Thoughts",
  journal= "Circularity Today",
  year   = 4004,
  volume = 1,
  number = 2,
  pages  = "3-33",
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[super]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\dots as was to be shown.\cite{uvw}
\bibliography{zzz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know your opinion, but I find superscript references even worse than footnote citations.

Comment: @egreg - I live in a country that celebrates neutrality. :-) Superscript-style numerical citation call-outs would certainly seem to invite confusion over what's an ordinary footnote marker and what's a citation call-out. That's probably one (amoung several) reasons why very few journals -- *Nature* being such a case -- practice superscript-style citation call-outs.

Comment: I had a paper completely ruined because the journal's style apparently changed and adopted superscript citations; phrases like “as proved in [1]” became ridiculous.